# Acceder a un array en base a string recibido en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo unos arrays tal que así:

```php
$columnas = [
    "ID" => "contacto,id",
    "NOMBRE" => "contacto,propiedades,nombre",
    "APELLIDOS" => "contacto,propiedades,apellidos",
    "NUMERO" => "contacto,propiedades,telefono",
    "FECHACREACION" => "contacto,creado",
    "FECHAMODIFICACION" => "contacto,modificado"
];

$contacto = [
    "id" => 1,
    "creado" => 1699010465,
    "modificado" => 1699430881,
    "propiedades" => [
        "nombre" => "Juanito",
        "apellidos" => "Verbenas",
        "numero" => 123456789,
    ]
];
```

Con los valores, necesito acceder a los valores del array `$contacto` con lo indicado en el array `$columnas` del tal modo, por ejemplo a "nombre":

```php
$tmp = explode(',', $columnas["NOMBRE"]);
$nombreObjeto = $tmp[0];
echo $$nombreObjeto[$tmp[1]][$tmp[2]]; //"Juanito"
```

Esto sería un ejemplo para acceder a "modificado":

```php
$tmp = explode(',', $columnas["FECHAMODIFICACION"]);
$nombreObjeto = $tmp[0];
echo $$nombreObjeto[$tmp[1]]; //"1699430881"
```

Esto lo tengo claro que funciona.

Ahora quiero saber como podría generar esos `echo` accediendo a los datos en función de la posición en el árbol en la que se encuentra el dato. Lo especifico con las comas en el array `$columnas` pero no se como generarlo como código.

En definitiva, quiero utilizar `$columnas` como "mapa" para obtener los valores de `$contacto`. En si sería una forma de automatizarlo.

O si quizá haya un medio mas sencillo o mejor.

Comment: Hola Marcos. Muchas gracias por tu contestación. Voy a tratar de explicarlo mejor. El array `$columnas` puede ser definido de diferentes maneras, así como el array `$contacto` tambien puede tener diferentes niveles y valores. Mi objetivo es utilizar `$columnas` como "mapa" para obtener los valores de `$contacto`. En si sería una forma de automatizarlo.

Comment: Yo atacaría en el origen, si pudiera, claro está. O sea, ¿por qué estás recibiendo esos datos tan pésimamente organizados? ¿No hay una forma de generarlos ordenadamente, de modo que no haya que recurrir a extravagancias para leerlos? El propósito de la programación es facilitar la vida, no complicarla. El programa usado para generar esos datos, o la lógica usada para modelarlos tienen una seria deficiencia y debería ser corregida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O integras `contacto` al arreglo o lo eliminas de la ruta.

Con dos iteraciones lo obtienes, la primera por cada columna y la segunda por cada elemento de la ruta, almacenando en una variable temporal `$tmp`.

```
$contacto = ['contacto' => $contacto];

$res = []; // resultado
foreach( $columnas as $cve => $val ){
   $tmp = $contacto;
   foreach( explode(',',$val) as $ruta )
      @$tmp = $tmp[$ruta];
   $res[$cve] = $tmp;
}
print_r($res);
```

Obtienes:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [NOMBRE] => Juanito
    [APELLIDOS] => Verbenas
    [NUMERO] => 
    [FECHACREACION] => 1699010465
    [FECHAMODIFICACION] => 1699430881
)
```

Comment: Me gusta y mas o menos es lo que tengo. Ahora lo dicho, pueden haber mas subsecciones para llegar a esos datos, ¿esto sería viable hacerlo con mas subniveles? ej; `contacto, propiedades, telefono, extensiones, extension1`

Comment: Es viable, no hay código duro para los niveles.

Answer (score 2):

Una solucion posible seria la siguiente:

```
$tmp = explode(',', $columnas["NOMBRE"]); 
$aux = ${$tmp[0]};
array_shift($tmp);
 
foreach($tmp as $key) {
    $aux = $aux[$key]; 
}

print_r($aux);
```

La idea inicial es hacer el explode de la clave que quieres analizar. Siguiendo tu ejemplo, he cogido la de NOMBRE.

El primer elemento (lo he llamado aux) coje la referencia de una variable (debe existir, por tanto, la variable `$contacto`).

el array_shift es para eliminar el primer elemento del listado de claves, ya que lo hemos usado. (asi no se utiliza luego en el for siguiente)

por ultimo, hay un foreach que itera sobre el resto de claves que hemos sacado de NOMBRE. por cada una de ellas, actualiza aux con el contenido de aux[$key].

Para ver un ejemplo, esta el print_r.

**NOTA:**
personalmente me parece un poco lioso que tengas el nombre de la variable (`contacto`) dentro del listado de keys. Si vas a usar esta forma, creo que es mejor extraer del listado dicha key, y que solo tengas que iterar por el resto de claves, haciendo referencia a la variable que tenga el contacto.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que algo de andar por casa podría ser esto:

```php
foreach ($contactos as $contact) {
    $datosContacto = [];
    foreach ($plantillaCampos as $keyColumna => $valueColumna) {
        $tmpUbicacionArbol = explode(',', $valueColumna);
        $objetoContacto = $tmpUbicacionArbol[0];
        if (isset($tmpUbicacionArbol[1]) === true) {
            if (isset($tmpUbicacionArbol[2]) === true) {
                if (isset($$objetoContacto[$tmpUbicacionArbol[1]][$tmpUbicacionArbol[2]]) === true) {
                    $dato = $$objetoContacto[$tmpUbicacionArbol[1]][$tmpUbicacionArbol[2]];
                }
            } else {
                if (isset($$objetoContacto[$tmpUbicacionArbol[1]]) === true) {
                    $dato = $$objetoContacto[$tmpUbicacionArbol[1]];
                }
            }
        }

        if (isset($datosContacto[$keyColumna]) === true) {
            $datosContacto[$keyColumna] .= ' '.$dato;
        } else {
            $datosContacto[$keyColumna] = $dato;
        }
    }
    $salida[] = $datosContacto;
}
```

Esto me devolvería algo así:

```
array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["nombre"]=>
    string(7) "Juanito"
    ["apellidos"]=>
    string(8) "Verbenas"
    ["numero"]=>
    int(123456789)
    ["creado"]=>
    string(10) "1699010465"
    ["modificado"]=>
    string(10) "1699430881"
  }
```

Seguramente tendré que tirar de recursividad u otro método mas eficiente, lo veo algo tosco y además limitado, tendré que controlar muchos niveles.

Answer (score 0):

Pensando en un caso de **normalización** podrías construir a partir de `$columnas` un array que te sirva para leer el contenido de `$contacto` automáticamente con el siguiente código:

```
$reader=array();
foreach($columnas as $c) {
    $tmp=explode(",",$c);
    $level = count($tmp);
    foreach($tmp as $k=>$v){
        if($level==3&&$k==1){
            if(!isset($reader[$v])){
                $reader[$v]=array();
            }
        }
        if($level==3&&$k==2){
            $reader[$tmp[$k-1]][]=($v==='telefono') ? 'numero' : $v;
        }
        if($level==2 && $k>0){
            $reader[]=$v;
        }      
    }
}
```

Tendrás un array como este:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [propiedades] => Array
        (
            [0] => nombre
            [1] => apellidos
            [2] => numero
        )

    [1] => creado
    [2] => modificado
)
```

Y podrás usarlo como *lector* de `$contacto` simplemente con esto:

```
foreach ($reader as $k=>$v){
    if(!is_array($v)) {
        printf("%s: %s %s",$v,$contacto[$v],PHP_EOL);
    } else {
        foreach ($v as $sub){
            printf("%s: %s %s",$sub,$contacto[$k][$sub],PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
id: 1 
nombre: Juanito 
apellidos: Verbenas 
numero: 123456789 
creado: 1699010465 
modificado: 1699430881
```

Sea como sea, yo atacaría este problema en el origen, buscando el motivo por el que `$columnas` viene tan mal estructurado, obligando a complicarse la vida a posteriori. No es sólo la organización, es incompatibilidad en los nombres, lo que hace las cosas harto complicadas, como el caso de `telefono` y de `numero`. Es ahí donde se ve la importancia de adoptar una convención de nombre organizada y coherente.

Comment: El objetivo de esto es que según me lleguen unos datos, los almaceno en una BBDD. El problema es que me llegan datos de muchos orígenes diferentes (pueden ser unos 30 o así). He puesto este ejemplo de como viene informado un contacto pero puede ser otra estructura muy distinta. Y tengo que, como bien dices, estandarizar esos datos para dejarlos coherentes en una BBDD. Conozco el origen de cada uno de ellos, por eso se me ocurre simplificarlo con una plantilla, por no crear muchisimos condicionales que a su vez creo que me complicarían mas mantenerlos.

Comment: @JoséGonzález siendo así, entonces sería incluso más simple. Puedes crear un array que sirva para mapear los datos. Para ello debes reflejar en ese array las diferentes posibilidades y usarlo para hacer las sustituciones. Por ejemplo, cuando viene un dato con la clave `telefono` cambiarla por `numero`. Sería importante saber por ejemplo si los datos siempre vienen organizados con la misma profundidad en cuanto a los niveles o si pueden venir más o menos anidados para crear, como dices, una plantilla en base a eso. Realmente no es tan complicado, basta con analizar tus `30` casos.

Comment: O por ejemplo ver si los nombres de clave de `$columnas` son siempre los mismos. Si es así, sería aún más simple, porque puedes usar esos nombres para mapear los datos, sabiendo que `NOMBRE`, `APELLIDOS` y `NUMERO` son propiedades.